# Run function on material node tree update

Tags: python, materials, node-editor, add-on, pynodes

I need to run a function when the user adds or removes a node from a material.

My first idea was to use *msgbus* to subscribe to `bpy.types.Nodes`. This works great for adding nodes but isn't called when a node is removed.

The next thing that came to mind is to track changes when the dependency graph is changed, but adding an app handler for that has the same effect. It works when nodes are added but not when they are removed.

Is there any way to track these changes and call a function when it happens?