# How to trigger on shader node update?

Tags: scripting, add-on, shader-nodes

I've been trying to create an add-on that should execute a function when I update anything on a shader node but I haven't managed to do it.

I thought it may not be possible and was about to give up when I stumbled upon the add-on "Node Preview", which seems to trigger on updates, so I guess it is possible.

Do you know how I could go about doing this?
Can we add a listener to the nodes, for example?

Comment: I see from https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180683/run-function-on-material-node-tree-update that some form of listener is possible, but I'm not an expert to take you to a listener for all updates on any nodes on any material.

Comment: @james_t , thanks, that was a good find! I'll look into that direction, though seeing that the question has no reply, I doubt I'll find a way to do what I want ...